# How to get available memory in IOS using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm porting an application I built in the past using Appcelerator. This app creates tons of dynamic content, so there is a function made to watch memory. In other words: Explanations like : use the DidReceiveMemoryWarning() to clear cache or use external tools to watch memory is not applicable. The end user must observe how big and heavy your on-the-fly content is consuming. The app made using Appcelerator uses Titanium.Platform.availableMemory and it's pretty easy to use.

I can't believe that's not possible using Xamarin. Is it really impossible ? I found a library converted from Objective-C to .Net, but it's probably very old because it can't compile.

Any help in this sense ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);` to get the current memory. If you need available memory, you can use `NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory`. You could then override your own behavior of `DidReceiveMemoryWarning()` to clean up excess resources.

EX:

```
public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
{
    photoMap.Clear ();
    View = null;
    photoImageView = null;
    toolbar = null;
    syncIsNeeded = true;
    base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
}
```

Comment: But this is "memory used" , right ? Can I assume that my available memory is NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory - System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false) ?

Comment: Yes that is used memory. Available would be done via `NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory`. One thing to keep in mind though is that the Titanium Mobile implementation might differ from these items. Here is the source: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/a8aceeaeee02ed9c8ea70c835a0e78960e254a55/iphone/Classes/PlatformModule.m#L254-L265

Comment: TY ! I will make some stress tests !